# How to get reference of the second window opened by a window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page opened in a browser's tab, running some JavaScript code which opens a google meet link. The meeting's **URL** looks something like this :- **https://meet.google.com/lookup/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?authuser=x&hs=xx**, which is a lookup one, so it first lands me on a **Sign in using** page, and then redirects me to the actual meeting. Now what I want to do is, execute some code as soon as that meeting tab gets closed. To check the state of that tab, I used the following piece of code.

```js
let windowRef = window.open(url, "_blank");
if(windowRef.closed) {
  
//Execute some code
   
}
```

But what ends up happening is that this **windowRef** gets assigned to the state of the **"Sign in using"** page, so as soon as I log in with my mail id to reach the actual meet URL, JavaScript thinks that my window is closed, and it executes the block. I want the same thing to happen but only after this redirection completes.

I am a beginner in JavaScript, so very very sorry if it's a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a timer to check if the pop up has been closed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

I have an example of this problem, but in react
https://medium.com/@enetoOlveda/open-a-popup-window-react-db81c8c180e5